# Using a 2D map in React to print a chessboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pretty new to react but instead of using the common js for loop I am trying to figure out how to use the .map() to achieve the same result.

```
 import React from 'react'
 import './styles/Board.css'
 import Tile from './Tile'
    
    const Board = () => {
        let board = []
        printBoard(board)
        return (
            <div className="board">
                { board }
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    const printBoard = (board) => {
        
        const boardY = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        const boardX = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
        
        for(let x = 0; x < boardX.length; x++) {
            for(let y = boardY.length - 1; y >= 0; --y) {
                //saves the position in each square ex: b1
                const pos = boardX[x] + "" + boardY[y]
                //paints the squares and the positions
                board.push(<Tile key={pos}  color={ (x + y) % 2 === 0 ? "dark" : "light" } pos={pos} />)
            }
        }
    }
    export default Board
```

> Current render

[image]

Comment: `map` doesn't solve all issues. I think in this case a nested for loop is fine for a bound case of 64 squares. Having said that `let board = []` should be in the `printBoard` function, and you should return it _from_ the function, and then you can do `{printBoard()}` In `Board` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the loops (outer and inner) when doing the same with `map` function. And the `y` had to be replaced with `(boardY.length - (yIndex + 1))` to get the decrementing index.

Try below

```
const Board = () => {
    return <div className="board">{printBoard()}</div>;
};

const printBoard = () => {
    const boardY = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    const boardX = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
    const boardYRevered = boardY.reverse();

    return boardYRevered.flatMap((y, yIndex) => {
        return boardX.map((x, xIndex) => {
            const pos = `${x}${y}`;
            return (
                <Tile
                    key={pos}
                    color={
                        (xIndex + (boardY.length - (yIndex + 1))) % 2 === 0
                            ? "dark"
                            : "light"
                    }
                    pos={pos}
                />
            );
        });
    });
};
```

NOTE: If you want a `2D array` of the chessboard, change `flatMap` to `map`.

Comment: @noobieCoder, check this out!!

Comment: But this is just introducing two `map`s where there were two for loops.

Comment: Hi @Andy, The given code already had two arrays declared and he wanted to know how to do the same iteration using the map function.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";

const Board = () => {
  const boardY = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
  const boardX = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"];
  const reverseY = boardY.reverse();

  return (
    <div className="board">
      {boardX.map((xValues,indexX) =>
        reverseY.map((yValues, indexY) => {
          const pos = xValues + "" + yValues;
          const colorIndex = indexX + indexY;
          <Tile key={pos}  color={ colorIndex % 2 === 0 ? "dark" : "light" } pos={pos} />
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Board;
```